# How to limit use to deploy application in the Android demo with LVL

Tags: android, eclipse, demo, android-lvl

I developed a paid app for Android and would like to develop a demo of it. The demo application to run x number of times and then give a message to purchase the full application.

I tried using both Google in: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html, but it still fails.

Does anyone have a walkthrough for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could increment instances in a db or a file. The db and text file would be easy to crack but using a binary file will be more robust.